# Hover over class and modify another class

Tags: html, css

I have a grid layout which inside is a sidebar with (64px) width,
the grid :

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar header"
    "sidebar content"
    "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 64px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 5% 92% auto;
  background-color: #efeff1;
}
```

how can i go about having that change to (160px) when i hover over the class sidebar,

.sidebar:

```
.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #1f2937;
  color: rgba(156, 163, 175);
  border-radius: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: You almost certainly can't. This would appear to require a parent selector which does not exist.

Comment: @Paulie_D but isnt container is the parent selector in this case? sidebar is inside it.

Comment: You can't affect the parent by hovering the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other commenters are correct, you can't change the parent from the child. But you can make the parent adapt to the child and just modify the child width.

```
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
```

Snippet here based on your code: https://codepen.io/29b6/pen/wvypzGq